# Retrieving data from Facebook pages (Tabs)

Tags: facebook

I am trying to pull data from Facebook pages. In this case, I need to retrieve the landing tab and the total number of tabs available on a specific page. I managed to pull those data using the "/tabs" connection, but is there a way to pull these two infos from a page I don't actually own (so I cannot access the /tabs connection) ?

Thanks in advance,

Nicolas.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your app is granted the 'manage_pages' permission you'll be able to use the '/tabs' connection to get the info you need. You don't need to be the page owner.